# How to get MongoRepository to return correct type when there are multiple types in the collection

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-mongo

Using Spring Boot, Spring Data (MongoDB). Say I have two classes that have some common super class, hence they are in the same collection:

```
@Document(collection = "automobiles")
public class Automobile {
   private String maker;
}
```

And the child classes:

```
@Document(collection = "automobiles") //not sure if this is needed, but put it in anyway
public class Truck extends Automobile {
}

@Document(collection = "automobiles") //not sure if this is needed, but put it in anyway
public class Van extends Automobile {
}
```

And the corresponding MongoRepository for each type:

```
public interface TruckRepository extends MongoRepository<Truck,String> {
}

public interface VanRepository extends MongoRepository<Van,String> {
}
```

**Problem**

```
@Autowired private TruckRepository truckRepository
@Autowired private VanRepository vanRepository

// save 1 of each in a fresh collection
truckRepository.save(new Truck(...));
vanRepository.save(new Van(...));

// try to get all vans
int size = vanRepository.findAll().size() // expect this to be 1, but is 2!
```

In fact findAll found all Automobiles including the Truck, and downcasted to Van (!!). How to make the Repository class more strict about types without introducing a type field?

**Dependencies**

- spring-boot-starter-parent 1.2.7 (parent pom)
- spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb
- spring-boot-starter-jersey
- spring-boot-starter-tomcat
- spring-boot-starter-actuator
- spring-boot-starter-test

Comment: When you insert records through spring data, do you have the _class field inserted ? My guess is your records are not marked by Spring, then when you are using the method findAll(), Spring cannot distinguish the type of the documents therefore Spring cannot know which one to retrieve

Comment: Thanks, the _class field is indeed in the document - which I gather is the default behavior anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025710/spring-data-mongodb-repositories-dont-implement-inheritance-correctly is the same issue

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate - thanks.

Comment: Just to be curious, did you try to pull up the @Document(collection = "automobiles") to the superclass ?

Comment: Yes that's what I had to begin with actually. Or did you mean only have it on the superclass and not the subclass?

Comment: Only the superclass annotated

Comment: Oh I see - just tested, same result.